# How to sort an int from a file

Tags: python, python-os

I have this code:

```
import glob
import os

for file in glob.glob("./data/*.jpg"):
    lel=(os.path.basename(file))
    lel = (os.path.splitext(lel)[0])
    list1 = lel
    list1 = [int(x) for x in list1]
    list1.sort()
    print(list1)
```

and it gives this output:

```
[0]
[1]
[0, 1]
[1, 1]
[1, 2]
[1, 3]
[1, 4]
[1, 5]
[1, 6]
[1, 7]
[1, 8]
[1, 9]
[2]
[0, 2]
[1, 2]
[2, 2]
[2, 3]
[2, 4]
[2, 5]
[2, 6]
[2, 7]
[2, 8]
[2, 9]
[3]
[0, 3]
[1, 3]
[2, 3]
[3, 3]
[3, 4]
[4]
[5]
[6]
[7]
[8]
[9]
```

is there a way to make it output this?:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
etc etc..
```

Comment: Please expalin better your desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell, you have files named `0.jpg`, up to `34.jpg`

You need to remove `[int(x) for x in list1]` because this gets a list *per file*

If you want to sort the numbers in ascending order rather than lexicographic, then make a list outside the loop, e.g.

```
import glob
import os

files = []
for file in glob.glob("./data/*.jpg"):
    lel = os.path.basename(file)
    lel = os.path.splitext(lel)[0]
    files.append(int(lel))
files.sort()
for f in files:
    print(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should work:

```py
import glob
import os

list1 = []

for file in glob.glob("./data/*.jpg"): # iterate over filename
    list1.append(
                 os.path.splitext(
                                  os.path.basename(file)
                                 )[0]
    ) # strip away path and extension and append to the list1
print(*sorted(list1)) # print it out
```

You were iterating over the letters of the filenames, and converting every letter to int.
You can even do it with a list comprehension:

```py
import glob
import os

list1 = [os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(filename))[0] for filename in glob.glob("./data/*.jpg")]
print(*sorted(list1))
```